# How do I change the tick color for CheckboxListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my checkbox widget all set up and would like to change the tick color to green when selected (currently it is white). So I managed to change the color of the checkbox when it is un-selected to white by adding a theme. I want to change the selected tick color to green, however I cant seem to find the right option under theme to do so.

Code:

```dart
  Widget buildResultTile(data) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: white),
      child:
        CheckboxListTile(
        activeColor: transparent,
        title: AutoSizeText(
          data,
          maxLines: 1,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: white,
          ),
        ),
        value: _serachSelectList.contains(data),
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              _serachSelectList.add(data);
            } else {
              _serachSelectList.remove(data);
            }
          });
        },
        secondary: const Icon(Icons.account_box, color: white),      
      )
    );
  }
```

Un-selected:

[image]

Selected (I want **only** the tick to be `Colors.green`):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ditch the `CheckboxListTile` and instead use a `Row` with an icon, text, and a simple `Checkbox` widget.

`Checkbox` provides [`checkColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/checkColor.html) property - which is responsible for the check/tick color and is white by default. Set the color you desire for that property and it should work.

e.g.

```dart
Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [

  Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Colors.white),
  Expanded(
    child: AutoSizeText(
      data,
      maxLines: 1,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: white,
      ),
    )
  ),
  Checkbox(
    value: _serachSelectList.contains(data),
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value) {
          _serachSelectList.add(data);
          setState((){ default_color = selected_color });
        } else {
          _serachSelectList.remove(data);
          setState((){ default_color = unselected_color });
        }
      });
    },
    checkColor: Colors.green,
    activeColor: Colors.transparent,
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  ),

]);
```

I did not test this code - you might encounter size & alignment issues that you would need to solve yourself. Nevertheless, the general idea is valid.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Actually, you might want to use `ListTile` instead of a `Row` for the sake of wider tap area - which is the entire `ListTile` size. You can follow [the source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7a4c33425d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox_list_tile.dart#L177) of `CheckboxListTile` as an example.

Answer (score 10):

To change the **fill** color of the checkbox in a `CheckboxListTile`, you can simply set the `toggleableActiveColor` property in your `ThemeData`:

```
ThemeData(
    // ... other theme values ...

    toggleableActiveColor: Colors.green
)
```

Changing the color of the **tick mark** is unfortunately impossible with `CheckboxListTile` since it doesn't expose the `checkColor` property of its `Checkbox` widget, so you are stuck with rolling your own list tile.

Comment: it is deprecated in flutter 3.0

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `checkColor` property of the CheckboxListTile-Widget to set the color of the checkmark:

```
CheckboxListTile(
  checkColor: Colors.black54, //sets checkmark color
  // ... other properties ...
)
```

(see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/37636)

To change the fill color of the checkbox see the answer of Magnus https://stackoverflow.com/a/56941539/702478

Answer (score 2):

please try this pesudo code,

```
Color selected_color = Colors.green;
Color unselected_color = Colors.transparent;
Color default_color = unselected_color ;

  Widget buildResultTile(data) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: white),
      child:
        CheckboxListTile(
        activeColor: default_color,
        title: AutoSizeText(
          data,
          maxLines: 1,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: white,
          ),
        ),
        value: _serachSelectList.contains(data),
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value) {
              _serachSelectList.add(data);
              setState((){ default_color = selected_color });
            } else {
              _serachSelectList.remove(data);
              setState((){ default_color = unselected_color });
            }
          });
        },
        secondary: const Icon(Icons.account_box, color: white),      
      )
    );
  }
```

i hope to help you

Comment: Hi, ok I tried your solution and it makes the fill of the checkbox green with the tick white, I still want the fill to be transparent while only the tick green.

Comment: @Rajdeep i'm not sure you can do that, otherwise you can use other library

Comment: @Rajdeep `CheckboxListTile` doesn't have another options to change tick of that, or i don't have any other information about that

Comment: You may be right haha, cause I cant seem to find anything that might help as well :'(

Answer (score 0):

it's working code for checkbox color change for flutter

checkColor: Colors.white,

activeColor: Colors.red,

```
CheckboxListTile(
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.red,
                value: checkedValue,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    checkedValue = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                controlAffinity:
                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
              ),
```